# New Column Calculations by Category using Max Date Field and Revenue Field

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, max

I have the following sample table shown below:

[image]

I want to create the following column: 'Most Recent Revenue' with the following criteria (see table below for desired result)
a. If the Date is not the max date by Account... then new column equals 0
b. If the Date is the max date by Account ... then new column equals Revenue

[image]

This is the code I have tried so far but it did not work:

```
df_MF_12mos.iloc[df_MF_12mos.groupby('Account')['Date'].agg(pd.Series.idxmax)]
```

TypeError: invalid type promotion

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df['Most Recent Revenue'] = df.groupby('Account').apply(lambda x: x.where(x['Date']==(x['Date']).max()))['Revenue'].fillna(0).astype(int)

print (df)
```

Output:

```
  Account       Date  Revenue  Most Recent Revenue
0       A 2017-02-28      100                    0
1       A 2017-03-31      300                  300
2       B 2016-01-13      500                    0
3       B 2016-02-29      200                    0
4       B 2016-03-31       10                   10
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# generate sample df
account = ['A','A','B','B','B']
date = pd.to_datetime(['02/28/2017','03/31/2017','01/13/2016',
                       '02/29/2016','03/31/2016'])
revenue = [100,300,500,200,10]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Account':account,'Date':date,'Revenue':revenue})

# compute Most Recent Revenue
def most_recent_rev(rows):
    return (rows.Date == rows.Date.max()) * rows.Revenue

df['Most Recent Revenue'] = (df.groupby(['Account'])
                               .apply(most_recent_rev)
                               .values)
```

Yields:

```
  Account       Date  Revenue  Most Recent Revenue
0       A 2017-02-28      100                    0
1       A 2017-03-31      300                  300
2       B 2016-01-13      500                    0
3       B 2016-02-29      200                    0
4       B 2016-03-31       10                   10
```